# Console output overflow

Tags: c++, loops, char, console-application

I'm trying to write a simple program that outputs the ascii characters 32 through 127, and when I do execute it does output the characters 32 through 127... over and over and over until it crashes. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char letter = 32;

for (letter = 32; letter <= 127; letter++) 
{
cout << letter << " ";
}

cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Which is kinda strange because if I change "letter" to an int variable, it works fine.

Comment: can you explain how it crashes?

Comment: well it just keeps outputting the ascii characters  37 through 127 on the screen over and over until I am prompted by the computer to end it

Comment: I mean 32 though 127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your `char` is signed, so it has values range -128..+127. Once it reaches 127 and you increment it, it becomes -128, which is still less than 127, and the loop runs infinitely. Use `int` or `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: For such things, I'd use `int`.  But of course, this means that you have to cast the value to a `char` before outputting it.  Otherwise, it will convert the `int` to the text representation of its numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is a data type with exactly 1 byte, which is commonly 8 bits. Since you have not specified the "signedness" of `char`, your compiler might have assumed a `signed char`, which ranges from -128 to 127.

That loop ran forever because incrementing a signed char from 127 results in  -128 due to an overflow, and -128 is still lower or equal to 127.
The easiest way to fix that would be using a larger integer.

```
int letter = 32;
for (letter = 32; letter <= 127 ; letter++) {
    cout << static_cast<char>(letter) << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` can have a value from -128..127, so it will always be `<= 127`.